# ValueError: Shape of passed values is (X,y), indices imply (X,y) when saving K-Fold 'test data' into dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, cross-validation, k-fold

I'm trying to save **all iteration** of my KFold 'test data, class, and predicted result' in one dataframe, but it returns `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1534, 3), indices imply (1, 3)`. How can I fix this?

My code :

```
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[test_index]
    
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    pred = model.predict(X_test)
    d = {'Tweet': X_test, 'Sentimen': y_test, 'Predicted': pred}
    df_test = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=[0])

df_test
```

Things to note :

- The Dataframe is just a means to make it looks neat and organized and easier to compare between the class and the predicted result. It can be in other format as long it can achieve the same result (e.g: CSV or Excel files).
- I'm trying to save all iteration and not only the last one. I read it use concat or append to achieve this, but I don't know how implement it inside a loop and with one dataframe.